# Mail inbox analyzer

Tags: python, api, email, statistics

I need a tool to access my email inbox via some convenient interface. For example, I need to get the timestamps of letters from some address. I need that data to build some mailing statistics.

What can I use to do that? Maybe there is an API in Thunderbird or something like that. I work under Windows.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Maybe I can do that with some Python library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a programming language that has a simple IMAP library which you can use to connect to your account. Then you will have to write a script that can do your statistics.

Since you asked for an API I assume that you know how to use a scripting language like PHP, Python or Ruby which all have an IMAP library available.

Comment: There you go. Update your post to make it a Python question. I'm a rubyist so I can't help you on that question :)

I'm sure you can load all folders and messages in Hashes/Arrays and then iterate through them. Make sure that you have a read only connection so you don't accidentally delete something.

Answer (score 1):

Is the mailbox local or on a server somewhere? If it's local, which mailbox format do you use? Thunderbird looks like it uses (a variation of?) mbox format, so you can probably read it with the [mailbox module](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html).

If it's in an IMAP server somewhere, try the [IMAP module](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html).

Both of these modules are part of the standard library.